# Textarea component which shows the count of written characters in React updates the value only after reload

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

Having the following component:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

import { TextareaTestIds } from '../utils/test-ids';

export interface TexareaProps extends React.TextareaHTMLAttributes<HTMLTextAreaElement> {
  maxLength?: number;
  id: string;
}

export function Textarea({ id, maxLength = 200, ...props }: TexareaProps) {
  const test = id;
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  useEffect(() => {
    const refElement = document.getElementById(test) as HTMLTextAreaElement;
    if (refElement) {
      setCount(refElement.value.length);
    }
  }, [test]);

  return (
    <div>
      {count}
      <textarea
        id={id}
        maxLength={maxLength}
        {...props}
      ></textarea>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Textarea;
```

This component returns a textarea where the user can write an input, also it shows the current count of introduced characters.

It is used inside a Modal, when first open the modal, no matter how much text is written, the value shown is 0 (value of count). If the modal is closed and opened again, the value is updated with the count of the text introduced before.

Is there a way to update the count in real time when writting?

Comment: why don't you take the value from the text area and count it directly? The useEffect always runs after the render of the component. You can get the prop value or defaultValue and count.

Comment: could you make an example? I'm not sure I get it

Comment: <div>{ (value || defaultValue).length }</div>

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simply like this,

```
import React from "react";

export interface TexareaProps
  extends React.TextareaHTMLAttributes<HTMLTextAreaElement> {
  maxLength?: number;
  id: string;
}

export const Textarea = React.forwardRef(
  ({ id = "my-id", maxLength = 200, ...props }: TexareaProps) => {
    const [value, setValue] = useState("");

    const count = value.length;
    return (
      <div className="relative flex flex-col">
        {count}
        <textarea
          {...props}
          value={value}
          maxLength={maxLength}
          onChange={(event) => setValue(event.target.value)}
        ></textarea>
      </div>
    );
  }
);

export default Textarea;
```

or if you get the value from props,

```
export const Textarea = React.forwardRef(
  ({ id = "my-id", maxLength = 200, ...props }: TexareaProps) => {
    
    const count = props.value.length;
    return (
      <div className="relative flex flex-col">
        {count}
        <textarea
          {...props}
          value={value}
          maxLength={maxLength}
        ></textarea>
      </div>
    );
  }
);
```

Comment: He doesn't need to have the state in the component. He can get the value from the ...props

Comment: it doesn't work, it shows 0 all the time, even after reopening the modal

Comment: I think there is an issue with your Modal :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a easy task. You can attach an `onInput` to the textarea and use `setCount(event.target.value.length}` to update the count.

https://jsfiddle.net/sean7777/Lvztbyuc/20/

Comment: I get an error saying: Property 'value' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.

Comment: @LeoMessi That is a typescript error. I have added a comment below that which shows how you might do it., line 12 (not tested)

Comment: is the comment visible?

Comment: Yes, the comment is visible.

Comment: it isn't.. maybe you didn't save it on fiddle

Comment: Try reloading tyhe page.

Comment: Oh wait, the fiddle isnt working. Here's the code:
`({target}) => setCount(<HTMLTextAreaElement>target.value.length)`

Comment: I've tried but still doesn't work, thank you for the effort

Answer (score 0):

You should not get the component value using the document. React has a virtual Dom and "thinking in React", the best way to do it, would be taking the value you pass to the Textarea.

```
 export const Textarea = ({ maxLength = 200, value = "", ...props }: TexareaProps) => 
 {
  
   return (
      <div className="relative flex flex-col">
       {value.length}
      <textarea
        {...props}
        value={value}
        maxLength={maxLength}
       ></textarea>
    </div>
      );
     }
  );
  export default Textarea;
```

Comment: I get this error: Property 'value' is missing in type '{ onChange: ChangeHandler; onBlur: ChangeHandler; ref: RefCallBack; name: string; id: string; label: string | undefined; containerClass: string; }' but required in type 'TexareaProps'.

Comment: Does it need to send it in a different way from the modal? I mean where the component is used, <Texarea value={...} />, what should be put here?